# Editing in chart.Correlation function R

Tags: r, correlation

Ps*If you have other useful `Correlation` function in R, these suggestions are welcome, too.

I want to add colnames of the dataset to the row and column side (instead of diagonal part) in  `chart.Correlation`  function. In addition to these I want to show corr results (in the upper triangle side) in the same size (for instance 12 pt). I know I should edit the  `chart.Correlation` function but I couldn't succeed. Please see the code below and pictures before and after.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(mtcars)
chart.Correlation(mtcars[,c(1,2,5,7)])
```

[image]

[image]